# Image Upload with GridFS using Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I am struggling to find an example tutorial to upload images with GridFs.

Can anyone provide me an code example of how to use GridFS in the actual server side controller to upload an image.

I am completely new to this.

Thanks for help.